# Python/pandas - Add word in column based on words in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with an xlsx file with pandas and I would like to add the word "bodypart" in a column if the preceding column contains a word in a predefined list of bodyparts.

Original Dataframe:

```
Sentence   Type
my hand    NaN
the fish   NaN
```

Result Dataframe:

```
Sentence   Type
my hand    bodypart
the fish   NaN
```

Nothing I've tried works. I feel I'm missing something very obvious. Here's my last (failed) attempt:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
bodyparts = ['lip ', 'lips ', 'foot ', 'feet ', 'heel ', 'heels ', 'hand ', 'hands ']

df = pd.read_excel(file)

for word in bodyparts :
    if word in df["Sentence"] : df["Type"] = df["Type"].replace(np.nan, "bodypart", regex = True)
```

I also tried this, with as variants "NaN" and NaN as the first argument of str.replace:

```
if word in df['Sentence'] : df["Type"] = df["Type"].str.replace("", "bodypart")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look into the `pandas.DataFrame.apply()` method. You can make a function that returns "bodypart" if an input is in the list `bodyparts`. You can then apply that function row-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a regex to search on word boundaries and then use that as an argument to `str.contains`, eg:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import re

bodyparts = ['lips?', 'foot', 'feet', 'heels?', 'hands?', 'legs?']
rx = re.compile('|'.join(r'\b{}\b'.format(el) for el in bodyparts))

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sentence': ['my hand', 'the fish', 'the rabbit leg', 'hand over', 'something', 'cabbage', 'slippage'],
    'Type': [np.nan] * 7
})

df.loc[df.Sentence.str.contains(rx), 'Type'] = 'bodypart'
```

Gives you:

```
         Sentence      Type
0         my hand  bodypart
1        the fish       NaN
2  the rabbit leg  bodypart
3       hand over  bodypart
4       something       NaN
5         cabbage       NaN
6        slippage       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

A dirty solution would involve checking the intersection of two sets.

set A is your list of body parts, set B is the set of words in the sentence

```
df['Sentence']\
     .apply(lambda x: 'bodypart' if set(x.split()) \
     .symmetric_difference(bodyparts) else None)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way :

```
df.loc[df.Sentence.isin(bodyparts),'Type']='Bodypart'
```

Before you must discard space in `bodyparts`:

```
bodyparts = {'lip','lips','foot','feet','heel','heels','hand','hands'}
```

`df.Sentence.isin(bodyparts)` select the good rows, and `Type` the column to set. `.loc` is the indexer which permit the modification.